# How to set diffrent images for every cell in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, tableview, cells, uitableview

I have TableView and I want to set different images for every cells.
Now I see same image for every cells

Here is my code :

```
@implementation SecondViewController

{
 NSArray *tableData;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Restore Edilen Evler", @"Sakarya Kenarı", @"Tekke Seyir Tepesi", @"Kilise",@"Akkaya Şelalesi",@"Kaplıcalar",nil];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableData count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"aktivite4.png"]; 

    return cell;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the image name based on the cell's indexPath. Update your `tableData` to include the image name, for example. Then you get the image name much like you get the cell's text. This can be accomplished by changing `tableData` to a an array of dictionaries where each dictionary has the text and the image name.

Comment: Is it?UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

Comment: No. The line that creates the cell doesn't change. The line where you set the image needs to change.